# Two natural numbers $K$ and $L$. $K$ has $L$ divisors, $L$ has $K/2$ divisors. How many divisors has $K+2L$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $K$ and $L$ be two natural numbers.
$K$ has $L$ divisors and $L$ has $\frac{K}{2}$ divisors.

How many divisors has $K+2L$ ?

Comment: Hint: Can you find some bound on a number of divisors of a number $n$? Further hint: if $k\mid n$, then either $k\leq\sqrt{n}$ or $n/k\leq\sqrt{n}$ (why?). How many such $k$ can there be?

Answer (score 1):

From the hint of Wojowu: There are at most $2\sqrt{n}$ divisors of $n$.

Thus, $L \le 2\sqrt{K}$ and $\frac{K}{2} \le 2\sqrt{L}$ implying $L^2 \le 16\sqrt{L}$. This follows $1 \le L \le 6$. From here you can find $K$ and then number of divisors of $K+2L$.